# Custom login message for single post pages only

Tags: login

I'm redirecting users to the login page only when the user tries to access a single post page using:

```
function force_login() {

    if (!is_single()) return;

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        auth_redirect();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to display a message in the login page just in this case, saying that the user needs to login to get access to this post.

I found that you can display a message in the login page using:

```
function post_login_message() {
    return '<p>Sample Login Message</p>';
}
add_filter( 'login_message', 'post_login_message' );
```

But this will display the same message everytime the user tries to login.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `is_single` doesn't mean what you think it means, and has nothing to do with post pagination

Comment: This also looks like an XY problem, the root problem here is "How do I get the number of pages in a post?"

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a misunderstanding of what `is_single` means, reading the docs clarifies this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

> Is the query for an existing single post?
>
> ## Description
>
> Works for any post type, except attachments and pages
>
> If the `$post` parameter is specified, this function will additionally check if the query is for one of the Posts specified.

So in a post listing, `is_single` is `false`, but on a blog post it is `true`. The same is true for a product, or another custom post type.

So this has more in common with `is_page` than pagination. A catch all function for this is `is_singular`

Remember, you can read the docs to verify things, and don't always assume. E.g. alternative bad assumptions that could be made:

- `is_single` determines if the site has a single blog, and returns false if it's a multisite
- `is_single` returns true if the post is the only post in a category
- `is_single` checks if the user has a single item in their shopping cart

### So How Do I Find Out How Many Pages a Post Has?

To display the pagination links, we use `wp_link_pages`, so we can pass the `echo` parameter and set it to false. This lets us test if it returned markup. If it did, then yes there's more than one page. If it did not, then no there is only 1 page

```
$pages = wp_link_pages( ['echo' => false ] );
if ( !empty( $pages ) ) {
    // more than 1 page
} else {
    // only 1 page
}
```

### A More Specific But Not As Elegant Method

There is a global variable named `$multipage` that is `true` if there is more than one page

```
global $multipage;
if ( $multipage ) {
    // there's more than one page
}
```

Comment: Sorry, bad english. I really meant "single post page" where I wrote "single page posts". The single.php page.

The problem is that I want to display a message in the login page only if it is redirecting the user after the login to a single post page.

Comment: Oh, that's **very** different to what your question described, you should edit your question to say that

Comment: Edited. Thanks Tom, and sorry for the misunderstanding.